# Create TCP Server accessible on remote networks

Tags: python, sockets, networking

A project I am working on has an Android app as a front-end and a Python program that would be used as the back-end.

I want to send data from the Android app (primarily images) to the Python program, do some processing and send the result back to the Android app.

I have found numerous tutorials that suggest using the `socket` module in python to create the server side, but all tutorials show the server on local network only (For testing purposes I created the client side also in Python, but it would be converted to Java later on)

**The server code:**

```
from requests import get
import socket

public_ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
print('My public IP address is: {}'.format(public_ip))

# getting the hostname by socket.gethostname() method
hostname = socket.gethostname()
# getting the IP address using socket.gethostbyname() method
local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
# printing the hostname and ip_address
print(f"Hostname: {hostname}")
print(f"IP Address: {local_ip}")
#
HOST = local_ip
PORT = 80  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)


with socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data.encode('utf-8'))
```

**The client code:**

```
import socket

HOST = '…'  # I modify it to the server's public IP address, as printed from the server code
PORT = 80  # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
with socket.create_connection((HOST, PORT)) as s:
    s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
    data = s.recv(1024)

print('Received', repr(data))
```

Using the code above, if I try using any port other than 80 I get  `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`. And for port 80, I get `TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out`.

In both cases, I try to connect from a device on another network.

I tried to use the `ping` command in Windows CMD to check the connection to the server, and I get 'connection refused message'.

I understand that the Firewall is what probably blocks the connection, but I don't know how to bypass it. I added a new rule in the Inbound Rules section (as suggested on other websites) but for no avail… The results were the same.

How can I make the connection between remote devices on different networks?

Thanks in advance ☺

Comment: You'd need to also set up port forwarding on your firewall/NAT device. You need to tell the device which internal machine to forward traffic that's bound to the port you're listening on. Note though, that this potentially opens you up to attacks. You should not expose machines to the internet unless you have them properly configured.

Comment: @Carcigenicate How do I do it¿ I have very basic knowledge about networking. I tried adding port-forwarding in my router settings but it didn't work

Comment: Honestly, if you don't know what you're doing, you probably shouldn't be self-hosting. You'd be better off setting up a Heroku or similar app and have them host for you. Heroku is great, or at least it was great for the simple case I used it for. You get a semi-customized URL (yournamehere.herokuapp.com), and people can connect right to that. It's free for basic usage. Hosting public facing servers yourself is, as I mentioned, dangerous.

Comment: Thanks, I would look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to connect to your server using a TCP socket connection, you need to make sure your server can listen on a port on a publically available IP address.

If the External IP address is assigned to your computer directly,
and if you run the server code on that computer, then the TCP port opened by the server code should be available on the internet.

However, IP addresses are often assigned to a modem/router in home networks,
instead of assigning them to any connected device directly.

To find out if your External IP address is assigned to the computer directly you can use tools that your OS support (eg. `ipconfig` on windows). If you can see the IP address returned by `api.ipify.org`, then it means your computer is connected directly. You can change your code to connect using publically exposed IP:

```
HOST = public_ip
```

If this is successful means your computer is assigned an external address directly. Which is highly unlikely.

There are several workarounds for this problem though:

**1) Configure your router to forward port**
Configure your router to forward all connections to it's external TCP port, to an internal host in your network which is assigned to your computer. Please find instructions [how it is done for your router](https://portforward.com/router.htm).

**2) Setup a remote proxy**

If you don't have permission to change your router settings you can set up a remote proxy listening on the TCP port. While there is a number of ways of doing this, very popular is to set up a [remote SSH tunnel](http://www.dirk-loss.de/ssh-port-forwarding.htm), for that you need to have a server with SSH access and an external IP. Run this command:

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:8080 root@your-ssh-server-host
```

You can also use a third-party service that exposes your private host on the internet like:

- [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) (Commercial, with free plans)
- [Localtunnel](https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/) (Open Source, can be self-hosted)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I would look into that

Comment: I tried using Ngrok but I keep getting "Connection closed by remote host". I downloaded the Windows software for Ngrok and executed `ngrok tcp 80` and after that the command you wrote `ssh -R …` on the local machine. The client still is not able to connect

Comment: 1) your server first 2) see what is your local IP address eg.: `IP Address: 127.0.1.1 ` 3) run ngrok to forward to that address eg.: `ngrok tcp 127.0.1.1:80` 4) see what is *Forwarding* host and port on ngrok proxy, eg.: `Forwarding                    tcp://8.tcp.ngrok.io:16844 -> 127.0.1.1:80` 5) Point your client to that address host  `8.tcp.ngrok.io` and port `16844`. Of course, these are just example values, but try providing your local IP to which ngrok should forward.

Comment: Awesome, it worked flawlessly. Thank you very much